# ChangePropertyAction does not affect FontWeight

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uwp, textblock

In my Universal Windows Platform app, I have a `TextBlock` whose `DataContext` is a custom class:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding OpeningHourDescription}" FontWeight="Light">
    ...
</TextBlock>
```

My custom class has a property `IsOpen`. If it is true, the `TextBlock` should change its color and font weight. I tried to define this by replacing the following XAML code within the `TextBlock` element:

```
<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding IsOpen}" Value="true">
        <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Foreground" >
            <Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                <Color>Lime</Color>
            </Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
        </Core:ChangePropertyAction>
        <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="FontWeight">
            <Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                <FontWeight>ExtraBold</FontWeight>
            </Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
        </Core:ChangePropertyAction>
    </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
</Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

The behavior itself is working: If `IsOpen` is true, the text is green. However, the `FontWeight` is not being set, the text never looks bold.

Curiously, swapping both `ChangePropertyAction` results in both actions not being applied.

Changing the `FontWeight` statically on the `TextBlock` works as expected. The issue also occurs when `FontWeight="Light"` is *not* set on the `TextBlock`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I modify the `FontWeight` with a `ChangePropertyAction`?

Comment: If I remember right, you can do it with a Storyboard and ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look into the Windows API, you'll see that a TextBlock.FontWeight property is of type `FontWeight`, which is a struct containing an Int16.

```
public struct FontWeight
{
    public System.UInt16 Weight;
}
```

If you set the XAML property on the control, it manages to convert the string to a `FontWeights` static property.

```
public sealed class FontWeights : IFontWeights
{
    public static FontWeight Black { get; }
    public static FontWeight Bold { get; }
    public static FontWeight ExtraBlack { get; }
    public static FontWeight ExtraBold { get; }
    public static FontWeight ExtraLight { get; }
    public static FontWeight Light { get; }
    public static FontWeight Medium { get; }
    public static FontWeight Normal { get; }
    public static FontWeight SemiBold { get; }
    public static FontWeight SemiLight { get; }
    public static FontWeight Thin { get; }
}
```

However in the trigger you're stating that the string you're entering is actually a `FontWeight` struct (and not a `FontWeights` property), thus the system has an error trying to convert the string.

```
<Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
     <FontWeight>ExtraBold</FontWeight>
</Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
```

---

**Solution**: You could use a `GoToStateAction` and VisualStates to fix your issue.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock"  Text="{Binding OpeningHourDescription}" FontWeight="Light">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding IsOpen}" Value="true">
            <core:GoToStateAction StateName="Open" >
            </core:GoToStateAction>
        </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBlock>
```

And add the correct states to your container control.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
        <VisualState x:Name="Open">
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="MyTextBlock.Foreground" Value="Lime" />
                <Setter Target="MyTextBlock.FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        ...
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Comment: In UWP you can use visual state [trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstate.statetriggers.aspx).

Comment: Looks like I can't use that since my `TextBlock` is actually a template for an `ItemsControl`, so I have multiple copies with independent states. Am I overlooking a way?

Comment: @fefrei In this case you are right. Inside `DataTemplate` you cannot use `StateTrigger`.

Comment: Too bad - I find the converter-solution to be quite ugly. Anyway, I'll accept your answer since it solves my minimal example, and I still learned something new `:-)`